# How do you say "snap judgment" in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese, hong-kong

There isn't a translation in the Cantonese dictionary. Is there a way to say "snap judgment" or the equivalent?

Comment: Are you referring to "the first impression" or "a quick decision"?

Comment: Both, tho particularly interested in the context when someone offers an opinion without trying something first, e.g., "that restaurant is terrible." How would you say, "It's best not to make snap judgments?"

Comment: Though I live in Hong Kong and I am a native Cantonese speaker, I seldom hear people use the term "snap judgement"  directly in conversation. For written Chinese, it should be equivalent to `莽下判斷`; if translate it into verbal Cantonese phrase, it should be `咁快下定論`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a Cantonese phrase equivalent to it. Usually we just use a sentence like "唔好咁快下结论" to express the idea of "Don't make a snap judgement".

Answer (score 0):

"唔好咁武斷"

It is a well-known saying for the 70s generation or earlier, but much less for the 80s generation and onwards.